# Display Images from REST service beside texts in Android ListView

Tags: java, android, rest, listview

I would like to display images from a Java REST service along side a name on an android ListView.

Assuming we have a list of Student Names and their passports in png formats on a REST server, I'll like to create a list on an Android app shows the passport of each student beside their names.

I'm able to display their names but I don't know how to go about returning their passports alongside their name on the REST service as well as displaying the passport on the ListView

Comment: please share whatever you tried so far

Comment: I'm stuck! Don't really know how to go about it. I only know how to display items in a listview but not dynamic images coming from REST service so I haven't tried anything regarding that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by converting my images to Base64 string and then sending them through JSON to the client.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `RecyclerView` with a `ViewHolder` which defines the display format for each item in the list (in your case a layout with a `TextView` and an `ImageView`) and a `RecyclerView.Adapter` to manage the list data.  You could then load the images using a library such as [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

A good basic tutorial on `RecyclerView` can be found here https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview

Comment: Please add Glide and Picasso official page address to your answer ;-)

Comment: In another scenario, this would be a good suggestion but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: If you provide specifics or code then we could help you.